# In Java what is idiomatically most similar to raising a Python ValueError?

Tags: java, python

If I were writing a Python function which received an argument with the correct type, but a value out of bounds, then I might throw a ValueError or one of its sub-classes.

For example, suppose I had a function which added up the prices on an invoice. If one of the prices had a negative value or one of the item-counts was not positive and non-zero I might raise VE.

My current project is in Java, but the situation is the same:

A pricing function accepts only numbers within a specific range - what's the most sensible kind of exception object to throw that tells another Java developer their input is out of that sensible range?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The standard library defines [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html):

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

Comment: No, it's called `IllegalArgumentException`, not `InvalidArgumentException`.

Answer (score 5):

I would use an `IllegalArgumentException` for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

[`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html).